# Could someone help me with python network pragram?

Tags: python, multithreading, ssl, python-multithreading

Write down the chatting program code base with SSL/TLS and MultiThreading.

there's a 3 things to follow.

1.when client connected client's ID and IP or Network interface information, network information.

2.when client send message you have to follow this form([Client ID@connect IP] Message ) everytime.

3.you have to show and explain flowchart with client and server program.

it's my final exam of network programing. but it's too hard for me. i couldn't write down the code. so i have to submit the paper with nothing. i don't know how to do. someone can explain how to code the program?

my code is

server.py

```
import socket   
import thread

print '---python chatting program---'

host = ''    
port = 27332

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)

users = []

def service(conn):

    try:

        name = conn.recv(1024)

        str = '*' + name + ' is entered.*'

        while conn:

            print str

            for each in users:

                each.send(str)

            str = name + ' : ' + conn.recv(1024)

    except:

        users.remove(conn)

        str = '*' + name + ' is out.*'

        print str

        if users:

            for each in users: each.send(str)

# thread.start_new_thread(service, ())

while 1:

    conn, addr = s.accept()

    global users

    users.append(conn)

    thread.start_new_thread(service, (conn, ))

    pass
```

client.py

```
import socket  
import thread

def handle(socket):

    while 1:

        data = socket.recv(1024)

        if not data:

            continue

        print data

    print 'handler is end.'


host = '127.0.0.1'    
port = 27332  

print 'enter your name.'

name = raw_input()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))

s.send(name)

thread.start_new_thread(handle, (s, ))

while 1:

    msg = raw_input()

    if not msg:

        continue

    s.send(msg)

s.close()

print '---chatting program is end---'
```

Answer (score 0):

The official Python documentation provides an example of how to use Python's native `socket` package to implement a simple echo server and client. The example itself contains essentially no real functionality (since the goal here is to demo the use of `socket`): the server echoes back everything it receives from the client. However, you can use this code as a basis, adding the functionality as required. If you use Python 3, you'll find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example), for Python 2 [see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example).

Now for the SSL/TLS part. Python has a native module `ssl` which is a TLS/SSL wrapper for socket objects; to cite the official Python documentation: the module "*provides access to Transport Layer Security (often known as “Secure Sockets Layer”) encryption and peer authentication facilities for network sockets*". If you use Python 3, you can find the documentation for the `ssl` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html?highlight=tls#module-ssl), for Python 2 [see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html?highlight=ssl#module-ssl).

The `ssl` module provides the class `ssl.SSLSocket`, which is derived from the socket.socket type, and provides a socket-like wrapper that also encrypts and decrypts the data going over the socket with SSL. The official documentation also contains example code (snippets) you can use to implement your exercise ([see e.g. here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html?highlight=tls#examples) for how to do SSL/TLS using `ssl` module in Python 3).